# how to configure akka in play framework 2.1 rc1 to production?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I am using play framework 2.1 RC1 with web sockets.

Each request to the web socket i open up to 4 akka job on Akka.system ,

and i have load tester that open 1000 connections and send request that use 4 akka job and it work very slow but when i see the CPU% and memory it doesn't reach the limit and the respond send serial so i thinking akka configure is wrong.
this is my akka config inside conf/application.conf :

```
play {

akka {

    actor {

        deployment {

            /actions {
                router = round-robin
                nr-of-instances = 1000
            }

            /promises {
                router = round-robin
                nr-of-instances = 1000
            }

        }

        retrieveBodyParserTimeout = 60 seconds

        actions-dispatcher = {
            fork-join-executor {
                parallelism-factor = 1000
                parallelism-max = 1000
                pool-size-max =1000
            }
        }

        promises-dispatcher = {
            fork-join-executor {
                parallelism-factor = 1000
                parallelism-max = 1000
                pool-size-max =1000
            }
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Why do you have 1000 threads per dispatcher? Are you using Await anywhere in your code? Or IO? If so, I bet your problem lies there.

Comment: I am try to open 10000 users  and than send request that use up to 7 akka jobs and do it fast i have 2 core with 4 ecu on ec2 large machine,
I am not using Await but i am using a lot of network calls.
my configuration my be wrong is there a good documentation and is this the place to put the akka configuration ?

Comment: Well, I can tell you that having a thousand threads on a machine with 2 cores is going to yield worse performance and scalability than having 50. Experiment with the settings. As for Play specific things I cannot comment.

Comment: Thanks a will lower the number to 50

Comment: No, I didn't mean that 50 is the optimal number. You'll have to tweak the settings to tune to your actual machine.